# Can anyone explain panchakshari mantra?

Tags: shiva, mantras

I know panchakshari mantra, But want to know clear explanation, What is intent of panchakshari mantra?

Answer (score 5):

Literal meaning of "Namah Shivaya" is "adoration to Shiva". "Namah Shivaya" also represents panchabhutas(5 elements). It is well explained by [Bodhinatha Veylanswami ji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhinatha_Veylanswami) in his book [Path to Siva](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/path-to-siva). I'll quote that part here:

> Namaḥ Śivāya is the most famous and holy of Saivite mantras, chanted daily by millions of devotees. **Namaḥ Śivāya means “adoration to Siva” and appears in the Yajur Veda in the famous Shri Rudram hymn to Siva.** It is known as the Panchakshara, or “five letters.” Each syllable has a meaning. Na is the Lord’s concealing grace and Ma is the world. Śi stands for Siva, Vā is His revealing grace, and Ya is the soul. The five letters also represent the five elements. **Na is earth, Ma is water, Śi is fire, Vā is air, and Ya is ether, or akasa.** This mantra is repeated verbally or mentally, drawing the mind in upon itself to cognize Lord Siva’s infinite, all-pervasive presence. It is freely sung and chanted by everyone, but it is most powerful when given by one’s guru. Gurudeva advised, “When life becomes difficult or strained, say to yourself ‘Śiva Śiva’ or ‘Aum Śivāya’ or ‘Namaḥ Śivāya.’ Mentally put it all at His feet.”

Comment: Thank you for your afford,  but want to know mantra intent.

Comment: @SaisivaA Read the part after akasa. It is mentioned.

Comment: Panchakshari mantra is actually only "namah shivaya" .. you can count that it has 5 aksharas.. with Om at the start the mantra becomes 6-syllabled i.e. shadkshara @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for correcting, updated the answer.